# Migration from Visual Studio to vscode - Fails on creating the .lib file can create .obj files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to migrate a large c++/python project from Visual Studio to vscode (frustrated on now Python3.8 support and the lagging IntelliSense in Visual Studio etc.).

So I've started with installing `vscode-solution-explorer`, `C/C++`, `C++ intellisense` , `code runner`, `Python` and a few other extensions to vscode and I've managed to build 2 out of 6 C++ projects but now I'm stuck on the third c++ project, bellow is a condensed part of the output from the terminal (it has a dependence on the frist two projects but it seems to find them (core and utils)).

```
....
C:\dev\project\msvc\auxiliary\Intermediate32\Debug\PID.obj
C:\dev\project\msvc\auxiliary\Intermediate32\Debug\SteeringEngine.obj
C:\dev\project\msvc\utils\Debug\utils.lib
C:\dev\project\msvc\core\Debug\core.lib
 Creating library C:\dev\project\msvc\auxiliary\..\project_name\systems\cppsystems\auxiliary.cp37-win32.lib and object C:\dev\project\msvc\auxiliary\..\project_name\systems\cppsystems\auxiliary.cp37-win32.exp
<bunch of similar errors>....
SteeringEngine.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall pysim::Variable::add(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,double *,class std::basic_s 
PID.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall pysim::CommonSystemImpl::__preStep(void)" (?__preStep@CommonSystemImpl@pysim@@UAEXXZ) [C:\dev\projects\msvc\auxiliary\auxiliary.vcxproj]
... more similar errors
```

This is the `c_cpp_properties.json`:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:/Dev/boost_1_71_0/libs/**", 
                "C:/Dev/boost_1_71_0/**",
                "C:/dev/libs/eigen-eigen-da9b4e14c255/**",
                "c:/python37-32/**",
                "c:/python37-32/include/**",
                "C:/dev/project/venv/Lib/site-packages/pysim/include/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.18362.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29333/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x86"
        },

        {
            "name": "Win64",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:/Dev/boost_1_71_0/libs/**", 
                "C:/Dev/boost_1_71_0/**",
                "C:/dev/libs/eigen-eigen-da9b4e14c255/**",
                "c:/python37-64/**",
                "c:/python37-64/include/**",
                "C:/dev/project/venv/Lib/site-packages/pysim/include/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.18362.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29333/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64"
        }

    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

And this is the first part of the `tasks.json`:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "Utils",
            "command": "msbuild",
            "args": ["${workspaceFolder}\\msvc\\utils\\",
                "/property:Configuration=Debug",
                "/property:Platform=x86",
                
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$msCompile"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: msbuild"
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "core",
            "command": "msbuild",
            "args": ["${workspaceFolder}\\msvc\\core\\"
                
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$msCompile"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: cl.exe"
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "auxiliary",
            "command": "msbuild",
            "args": ["${workspaceFolder}\\msvc\\auxiliary\\",
                "/t:build",
                
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$msCompile"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: msbuild"
        },
        ....
```

Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

On the similar topic in the auxilliary.vcproj I've included paths for x32 and x64 and for debug/release like this: `<ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">`. Where and how do I select this? (looks like I've selected the 32bit debug, but where is that selected?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bah, this error was caused by a mixture of python versions and x64 and x32 bits systems :(